# Is the following text grammatically correct?

Tags: conditionals

I've encountered the following text:

> The war might have continued, at terrible cost to all three countries,
> had not domestic turmoil in Japan, coupled with effective disruption
> of Japanese supply lines by the Korean navy, led to the recall of
> Japanese troops from Korea in 1598.

I suspect this is a third conditional, but the "if" is missing.

Is the text grammatically correct? If so, what is the grammar behind it?

Comment: Not a grammar expert, so I'll leave that to someone who is, but as a native speaker I think it would sound much more natural if "not" were moved: "had domestic turmoil in Japan, coupled with..., not led to the recall".

Comment: 'Had not domestic turmoil etc.' = 'If .domestic turmoil etc. had not".